# How to fix this type mismatch error in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types

I got the following error in Scala REPL:

```
scala> trait Foo[T] { def foo[T]:T  }
defined trait Foo

scala> object FooInt extends Foo[Int] { def foo[Int] = 0 }
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.Int(0)
required: Int
   object FooInt extends Foo[Int] { def foo[Int] = 0 }
                                                   ^
```

I am wondering what it exactly means and how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably don't need that type parameter on the method `foo`. The problem is that it's shadowing the type parameter of it's trait `Foo`, but it's not the same.

```
 object FooInt extends Foo[Int] { 
     def foo[Int] = 0 
          //  ^ This is a type parameter named Int, not Int the class.
 }
```

Likewise,

```
 trait Foo[T] { def foo[T]: T  }
           ^ not the    ^
              same T
```

You should simply remove it:

```
 trait Foo[T] { def foo: T  }
 object FooInt extends Foo[Int] { def foo = 0 }
```